# Access violation while reading in a multithreaded producer and consumer application

Tags: c, windows, multithreading, access-violation, release-mode

I have made a multi-threaded producer/consumer application which I have been struggling with for a couple of days now. The producer(s) place(s) Fibonacci numbers into a circular buffer and the consumer(s) take numbers from the buffer until the specified limit is reached.

I have protected the circular buffer with a mutex (Mutual Exclusion) which should prevent multiple threads from accessing the same data. I have also set up events which should prevent the producer(s) from overflowing the buffer, and the consumer(s) from accessing the buffer while it is empty.

While I say this, I still notice that the buffer is being accessed by consumers while it is empty. This is why I have added a break to the consumer thread (I do not quite understand why this would be necessary).

I'm also occasionally receiving "Access violation reading location" errors, which I just can't comprehend. I have noticed those occur more often up to almost always when creating more threads. I thought these might occur because the consumer was trying to read the buffer at locations that do not exist, but I have seen that this is not the case.

What might be causing my issues? Is it possible that multiple threads pass the WaitForSingleObject on the Mutex?

This is the Fibonacci.c

```
#include "Fibonacci.h"

#define MINIMUM 1
#define MAXIMUM 5

HANDLE eBufferNotFull;
HANDLE eBufferNotEmpty;
HANDLE fiboMutex;
HANDLE bufferMutex;

CircularBuffer *buffer;
Fibonumbers numbers;

int main(void) {

    uint8_t amountOfProducers, amountOfConsumers, size;
    ThreadStruct consumerInfo, producerInfo;

    setValue("The amount of producers", &amountOfProducers, MINIMUM, MAXIMUM);
    setValue("The amount of consumers", &amountOfConsumers, MINIMUM, MAXIMUM);
    setValue("The size of the buffer", &size, 1, 80);

    resetFibo(&numbers);
    setValue("The sleeping time for producers", &producerInfo.sleep, 0, 10000);
    setValue("The sleeping time for consumers", &consumerInfo.sleep, 0, 10000);
    setValue("The limit for the fibonumber", &producerInfo.limit, 0, 35000000000000000);

    consumerInfo.limit = producerInfo.limit;

    HANDLE hProducer[MAXIMUM];
    DWORD dwProducer[MAXIMUM];

    HANDLE hConsumer[MAXIMUM];
    DWORD dwConsumer[MAXIMUM];

    buffer = createBuffer(size);

    /* Create the Mutexes */
    fiboMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);
    bufferMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, NULL);

    /* Create the Events */
    eBufferNotFull = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, TRUE, TEXT("buffer_niet_vol"));

    eBufferNotEmpty = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("buffer_niet_leeg"));

    /* Create the producer threads*/
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfProducers; ++i) {
        hProducer[i] = CreateThread(NULL,                               // No security
            0,                                  // Use default stack size             
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)producer,
            &producerInfo,                      // Thread argument
            0,                                  // Child became running
            (LPDWORD)&dwProducer[i]);           // Child id
    }

    /* Create the consumer threads*/
    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfConsumers; ++i) {
        hConsumer[i] = CreateThread(NULL,                               // No security
            0,                                  // Use default stack size             
            (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)consumer,
            &consumerInfo,                      // Thread argument
            0,                                  // Child became running
            (LPDWORD)&dwConsumer[i]);           // Child id
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(amountOfProducers, hProducer, true, INFINITE);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(amountOfConsumers, hConsumer, true, INFINITE);

    deleteBuffer(buffer);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

DWORD WINAPI producer(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    ThreadStruct *info = (ThreadStruct *)lpParameter;
    while (true) {
        Sleep(info->sleep);

        WaitForSingleObject(fiboMutex, INFINITE);   // Lock the fibonumber struct
        createNewFibonumber();

        if (numbers.currentFibo > info->limit) {
            ReleaseMutex(fiboMutex);                // Release the fibonumber struct
            ExitThread(EXIT_SUCCESS);
        }

        WaitForSingleObject(eBufferNotFull, INFINITE);

        WaitForSingleObject(bufferMutex, INFINITE);
        putElement(buffer, numbers.currentFibo);
        ReleaseMutex(fiboMutex);                    // Release the fibonumber struct
        ReleaseMutex(bufferMutex);

        SetEvent(eBufferNotEmpty);
    }
}

DWORD WINAPI consumer(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    ThreadStruct *info = (ThreadStruct *)lpParameter;
    while (true) {
        Sleep(info->sleep);

        WaitForSingleObject(eBufferNotEmpty, INFINITE);

        WaitForSingleObject(bufferMutex, INFINITE);
        printf("                            fibogetal: %i \n", getElement(buffer));
        ReleaseMutex(bufferMutex);

        SetEvent(eBufferNotFull);
    }
    ExitThread(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void createNewFibonumber() {
    uint64_t i = numbers.currentFibo;
    numbers.currentFibo += numbers.lastFibo;
    numbers.lastFibo = i;
}

void resetFibo(Fibonumbers *numbers) {
    numbers->lastFibo = 0;
    numbers->currentFibo = 1;
}

void setValue(char *text, void *intpointer, uint64_t minimum, uint64_t maximum) {
    printf("%s\n", text);
    do {
        *(uint64_t *)intpointer = 0;
        printf("Enter a value from %lli up to %lli : ", minimum, maximum);
        scanf_s("%lli", intpointer);
    } while (*(uint64_t *)intpointer < minimum || *(uint64_t *)intpointer > maximum);
}
```

Fibonacci.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Buffer.h"

typedef struct {
    uint64_t currentFibo;
    uint64_t lastFibo;
} Fibonumbers;

typedef struct {
    uint64_t limit;
    uint16_t sleep;
} ThreadStruct;

/*
*
*/
DWORD WINAPI producer(LPVOID lpParameter);

/*
*
*/
DWORD WINAPI consumer(LPVOID lpParameter);

/*
*
*/
void createNewFibonumber();

/*
*
*/
void resetFibo(Fibonumbers *numbers);

/*
*
*/
void setValue(char *text, void *intpointer, uint64_t minimum, uint64_t maximum);
```

And the Buffer.c

```
#include "Buffer.h"

CircularBuffer *createBuffer(uint8_t size) {
    CircularBuffer *buffer = (CircularBuffer *)calloc(1, sizeof(CircularBuffer));
    buffer->size = size;
    buffer->count = 0;
    buffer->start = 0;
    buffer->end = 0;
    buffer->buffer = (uint64_t *)calloc(buffer->size, sizeof(uint64_t));

    return buffer;
}

void deleteBuffer(CircularBuffer *buffer) {
    if (buffer) {
        free(buffer->buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}

void putElement(CircularBuffer *buffer, uint64_t element) {
    buffer->count++;
    buffer->buffer[buffer->start] = element;
    buffer->start++;

    if (buffer->start == buffer->size) {
        buffer->start = 0;
    }

    printf("put: %i items in buffer.\n", buffer->count);
}

uint64_t getElement(CircularBuffer *buffer) {
    buffer->count--;
    uint64_t value = buffer->buffer[buffer->end];
    buffer->end++;

    if (buffer->end == buffer->size) {
        buffer->end = 0;
    }

    printf("                            get: %i items in buffer.\n", buffer->count);

    return value;
}

bool isBufferFull(CircularBuffer *buffer) {
    return (buffer->count == buffer->size);
}

bool isBufferEmpty(CircularBuffer *buffer) {
    return (buffer->count == 0);
}
```

Buffer.h

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    uint64_t *buffer;
    uint8_t size;
    uint8_t count;
    uint8_t start;
    uint8_t end;
} CircularBuffer;

CircularBuffer *createBuffer(uint8_t size);

void deleteBuffer(CircularBuffer *buffer);

void putElement(CircularBuffer *buffer, uint64_t element);

uint64_t getElement(CircularBuffer *buffer);

bool isBufferFull(CircularBuffer *buffer);

bool isBufferEmpty(CircularBuffer *buffer);
```

If someone wishes to also check out the header files, please say so.

edit: I have updated the code, it is now fully functional.
edit2: The program works when I build it under debug mode, but when build under release mode it seems to not start the threads.

Comment: Can you post a specific failure case? Saying that you have the files in your post (what is the IDE/compiler message about?)
My point is: try to be specific about your problem and you'll have far more possibilities to solve it.

Comment: BTW, `if (isBufferEmpty(buffer)) break;` is probably wrong; if the consumers outrace the producers, all the consumer threads will exit.  You don't want that to happen until all the producer threads have exited.

Comment: The thread functions must have the signature `DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(LPVOID lpParameter);`

Comment: I have done so now, but the program still does not fully function in release-mode.

Comment: What exactly goes wrong?  With the current code, only one thread is ever going to be running at a time, and the program hangs once it has finished processing, but other than that it looks as if it should work.  (You may want to add some error checking.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston The consumer and producer threads never start running and the program exits after the user has given all the required data. While in debug mode the program has multiple threads running at a time and is fully functional.

Comment: Are you sure the code posted is exactly the same as the code you're now running?  Because I really can't see how more than one thread could run at a time - the `eBufferNotEmpty` and `eBufferNotFull` events should act as a mutex.  (If you post the `.h` files I'll try it out myself.)  You should check the return value of CreateThread to make sure it is not failing.

Comment: Works the same for me (i.e., only one active thread at a time, hangs on exit, but otherwise working fine) whether in release or debug mode.  What input parameters are you using?  What compiler?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm using Visual Studio. What exactly do you mean with one active thread at a time? What is the output, you are getting? This is the output I get when I run it in debug mode: [image](http://i.imgur.com/Gj5KTsD.png) (this is the desired output) It just exits right after I have answered all input in release-mode.

Comment: I get the same output as shown in the image you posted, even when I'm running in release mode.  Have you added error checking for the calls to `CreateThread` and `WaitForMultipleObjects`?  Or tried running the release version in the debugger?

Comment: Actually looking more closely, one producer thread can be running createNewFibonumber() at the same time that one consumer thread is running printf().  But the producer thread can't add the fibonumber to the queue until the consumer thread calls `SetEvent(eBufferNotFull)`, and then the consumer thread has to wait untli the producer thread calls `SetEvent(eBufferNotEmpty)`.  The upshot is that there's never more than one element in the buffer (as you see in your screenshot) - making having a buffer a bit pointless!

Comment: Also, note that because you're using named events, the program may misbehave if another instance is still running.  It might be worth trying unnamed events (just pass `NULL` instead of the strings) just in case that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Wrong sized allocation

I find this line to be highly suspicious:

```
buffer->buffer = (uint64_t *)calloc(buffer->size, sizeof(unsigned int));
```

If `buffer->buffer` is an array of `uint64_t`, why are you using `sizeof(unsigned int)` to allocate it?  I don't know if that is your problem, but it's at least one thing that should be fixed up.

Comment: The sizeof(unsigned int) was the problem, that was sloppy.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Thanks.  I thought that events worked like semaphores but if not then my answer was wrong.  I removed that part of the answer.

Comment: No, events definitely don't work like semaphores - calling SetEvent on an event object that is already set is a no-op. :-)  The OPs design is indeed sub-optimal though, under some circumstances consumer threads will be sitting waiting even though there is work they could be doing.  (Using a manual-reset event would help.)